# Saving Three.js Canvas as image

Tags: image, three.js, render

We have a Carport Designer that uses three.js canvas.  I'd like to place a download button to capture the drawing as an image.  How would I do that?  I've read tons of stuff but nothing I understand.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This ended up working for me;

I had to change `preserveDrawingBuffer` to true.

html

```
<button id="save">Download Image</button>
```

```
<script> document.getElementById('save').onclick=()=>{ saveImage() } function saveImage() { const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0] const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); const a = document.createElement("a"); a.href = image.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream'); a.download="image.png" a.click(); } </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image object via `canvas.toDataURL` and then download it:

```
<!-- html -->
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="btn-download">Download</button>

// javascript
const downloadButton = document.getElementById('btn-download');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

downloadButton.addEventListener('click', downloadScreenshot);

function downloadScreenshot() {
  const screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = screenshot;
  a.download = "screenshot.png";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Comment: Been playing around with the code more and now I have it saving as the correct size, but with a black background... still don't know :/

Comment: This worked for me.  document.getElementById('save').onclick=()=>{
  saveImage()
}

function saveImage() {
  const canvas =  document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]
  const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = image.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
  a.download="carport.png"
  a.click();
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a renderer like below

```
var renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true,preserveDrawingBuffer: true })
```

> Don't forget to add {alpha: true,preserveDrawingBuffer: true } as params

Create a function for download

```
public downloadPattern() {
  let canvasImage = renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/png');
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', downloadPattern);
  a.setAttribute('download', new Date().getTime() + '.png');
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}
```